# svn info command hit my svn server to find the server revision number?

Tags: linux, svn, subversive

I doubted that weather the command I run `svn info` on my machine, hits/requests my svn server? Or it just finds the ServerRevision & local revision locallly?

Here is the output of svn info for reference:

```
Path: ....
URL: https://....
Repository Root: https://...
Repository UUID: ....
Revision: 1787
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ....
Last Changed Rev: 1785
Last Changed Date: 2015-01-06 07:44:21 -0600 (Tue, 06 Jan 2015)
```

How does 1787 came in here?
If they send a request to my server, will it request every time I run the command? Or it sends request only when necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last revision is stored locally in your local svn repository cache. There is no request sent to the server when you run `svn info`. The revision is downloaded when you run `svn update`. Therefore, it may not be up-to-date.

If we turn off the network, `svn info` still works. Observe:

```
dionyziz@erdos ~/valgrind % ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host
dionyziz@erdos ~/valgrind % svn info|grep Rev
Revision: 14853
Last Changed Rev: 14853
dionyziz@erdos ~/valgrind % svn update
Updating '.':
svn: E670008: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk'
svn: E670008: Unknown hostname 'svn.valgrind.org'
```

As you can see, `svn info` works without a network connection, but `svn update` doesn't. This indicates that the data is cached locally.

Indeed, let's take a look at SVN's meta directory `.svn`. This contains a SQLite database which contains all the information you need to extract the most recent revision:

```
dionyziz@erdos ~/valgrind/.svn % sqlite3 wc.db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
sqlite> SELECT revision FROM nodes ORDER BY revision DESC LIMIT 1;
14853
```

Comment: awesome answer, however at least one request should be sent to update the cache? Am I right?

Comment: Correct. You can run `svn update` to update your cache. If you don't run it explicitly, `svn info` may show outdated information.

Comment: Interestingly even after making a commit, `svn info` won't show the new revision number and won't update the last changed author + date until running `svn update` again.

Comment: But, you *can* give a URL to `svn info`, in which case it *will* contact the server. It's only when you give it a local path in the working copy that it doesn't contact the server.